# Pyvis graph wont stop moving

Tags: python, pyvis

I'm trying to make a project where I create a graph from a python project.
I have this code

```
import os
import sys
import re
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.physics import Physics
from radon.visitors import ComplexityVisitor

from pyvis.network import Network

rootDir ="/home/ask/Git/Zeeguu-API"
depth = int(sys.argv[1])
class directory:
    def __init__(self,path, ParentDir = None,ChildrenDirs = [] , PyChildren = []) -> None:
        self.path = path
        self.parentDir = ParentDir
        self.pyChildren = ChildrenDirs
        self.pyChildren = PyChildren


def getComplexityoffile(file : str):
    f = open(file, "r")
    s = f.read()
    return ComplexityVisitor.from_code(s).total_complexity        
 
def getParentOfDir(dir: str):
    cutlast = dir.split("/")[:-1]
    join = "/".join(cutlast)
    if join:
        return join
    else:
        return "./"

def extract_importandClass_from_line(unline):

    x = re.search("^import (\S+)", unline) 
    x = re.search("^from (\S+)", unline) 
    return x.group(1)#, c.group(1).split('(')[0]



def getimportsforfile(file):
    lines = [line for line in open(file)]
    classes = []
    all_imports = []

        
    for line in lines:
        try:
            imports = extract_importandClass_from_line(line)
            tmp = imports.rsplit('.',1)
            importEnd = tmp[-1]
            # importsimports
            importsFormatted = imports.replace('.', '/')
            finalimport = importsFormatted[1:] if importsFormatted.startswith('/') else importsFormatted
            all_imports.append(importsFormatted)
        except:
            continue
            
  
    return all_imports

NodesAndComplexity = {} # (node/complexity in folder)

# ting jeg vil bruge til at holdestyr på dependencies
Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs = {}
pythonFile_to_imports = {} # (Fille importing, file/dir imported)




dirsForDisplay = set()
# mapping files to parent directories
parenDirToChildDir = {} # (parent, [list of children])
G = nx.DiGraph()
isRoot = True
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    pyfiles = list(filter(lambda a : a.endswith('.py'), files)) 
    thisDir = root.replace(rootDir, '')
    splitDIR = thisDir[1:].split("/")[:depth]
    if not isRoot:
        displayableDir = "/" + "/".join(splitDIR)
    else:
        displayableDir = "./"
        isRoot = False
    # if there is python files on this directory 

    referentialDIr = thisDir[1:] if thisDir.startswith('/') else thisDir

    Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs[referentialDIr] = displayableDir

    if (pyfiles):
        accumulateComplexity = 0
        for f in pyfiles:
            filepath = root + "/"+ f
            imports = getimportsforfile(filepath)
            logFile = thisDir + "/" + f[:-3]
            accumulateComplexity = accumulateComplexity + getComplexityoffile(filepath)

            removedslashFromLogfile = logFile[1:] if logFile.startswith('/') else logFile
            Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs[removedslashFromLogfile] = displayableDir
            pythonFile_to_imports[removedslashFromLogfile] = imports

        if displayableDir not in NodesAndComplexity:
            NodesAndComplexity[displayableDir] = accumulateComplexity
        else:
            NodesAndComplexity[displayableDir] = NodesAndComplexity[displayableDir] + accumulateComplexity


        if (displayableDir not in dirsForDisplay):
            dirsForDisplay.add(thisDir)
            G.add_node(displayableDir, Physics=False)
            if not isRoot and displayableDir != "./":
                parent = getParentOfDir(displayableDir)
                G.add_edge(parent, displayableDir)


# setting node sizes
for importingfile, importlist in  pythonFile_to_imports.items():

    for importt in importlist:
        if importt in Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs:
            fromf = Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs[importingfile]
            to =  Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs[importt]
            if fromf != to:
                G.add_edge(Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs[importingfile],Map_Dirs_And_Files_To_Displaybledirs[importt], color="red")

for node, complexity in NodesAndComplexity.items():
    complexixtyDisplay = complexity / 2
    G.nodes[node]["size"] = complexixtyDisplay


Displayer = Network(directed=True, height="1500px", width="100%")


Displayer.from_nx(G)
Displayer.barnes_hut(overlap=1)

Displayer.show_buttons(filter_=["physics"])
Displayer.show("pik.html")
```

This creates the graph just fine. However, when I create it, the graph is flying around my screen, and it is impossible to actually get a looks at it.

If I remove  `Displayer.barnes_hut(overlap=1)`, then it doesnt move, but then the nodes are all just bunched up on top of eachother, and again it is impossible to decipher the graph.

How do I get a graph that is both standing (reasonably) still and readable?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the `show_buttons` function add all the buttons, and after creating the `pik.html` file, open the html file in Google Chrome. In the buttons option
there will be font category, there you can disable the [physics option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8sJB.png).

From then on the nodes will not move and you can distribute the nodes as you want by moving them.